# How to set panning limits on WPF Canvas based on zoom level?

Tags: wpf, math, canvas, geometry, zooming

I'm trying to set **zooming and panning limits** on a control I found here:
https://wpfextensions.codeplex.com

I managed to set zooming limits, but now I'm having **trouble setting the panning limits** so that you can't pan the object inside the canvas, outside the view.

I succeeded in setting the limits, but only when the zoom level is 1 (`Zoom == 1`, so no zoom), but the moment you **increase the zoom** (by rotating the mouse wheel) **things start to go wrong**: the limits are set, but they are not set correctly.

In order to set them correctly I have to take into consideration the `deltaZoom` (the amount zoom changed compared to the previous zoom value).

## Small demo project

I have created a simple, standalone project where I can reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/igorpopovio/CanvasZoomPan

The project shows a desktop window with the `ZoomControl` (canvas with `ScaleTransform`, `TranslateTransform` and a bunch of dependency properties to make it easier to work with the transforms). The `ZoomControl` contains a red square and the window contains the `ZoomControl` and a debug list of properties so I can see live how they change based on left click drag and mouse wheel zoom.

## Expected vs actual behaviour

**Expected behaviour**: object/red square edge cannot get out of the current view.

[image: Expected behaviour]

**Actual behaviour**: object/red square edge gets out of the current view (still has limits, but aren't correctly set).

[image: Actual behaviour]

## Code explanations

All the action happens in [**this file**](https://github.com/igorpopovio/CanvasZoomPan/blob/master/ZoomControl/ZoomControl.cs) and the important bits are:

- the panning limits: `MinTranslateX, MaxTranslateX; MinTranslateY, MaxTranslateY`
- the current panning: `TranslateX, TranslateY`
- the current zoom: `Zoom`
- the amount zoom changed: `deltaZoom` (local variable)
- the `Zoom_PropertyChanged` method
- the `LimitZoomingAndPanning` method

## What I tried

In the `LimitZoomingAndPanning` method I set the translation/panning limits which are working for `Zoom == 1` (`deltaZoom == 1`), but are giving incorrect limits for any other `Zoom` values:

```
MinTranslateX = box.BottomLeft.X * deltaZoom;
MinTranslateY = box.BottomLeft.Y * deltaZoom;

MaxTranslateX = ActualWidth - box.Size.Width * deltaZoom;
MaxTranslateY = ActualHeight - box.Size.Height * deltaZoom;
```

The `box` variable is actually the bounding box of the object inside the canvas. `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` are the size of the canvas on which the object is rendered.

Logically, all the translation/panning limits should depend on `deltaZoom`.

**Maybe I'm missing something?**

Answer (score 0):

I originally tried doing the same thing with the `ZoomAndPanControl` but wasn't able to achieve what I wanted so I ended up writing my own control to provide a constrained zoom and pan control.

I have packaged this control up on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Han.Wpf.ViewportControl/1.0.0) but it can be found on my [gist](https://gist.github.com/ahancock1/a2958f7eedd3e8d13e6ddda8feef0a65) and on my [github](https://github.com/ahancock1/Han.Wpf.ViewportControl) with a demo project loading an image into the viewport control.

```
PM > Install-Package Han.Wpf.ViewportControl
```

Usage:

```
<controls:Viewport MinZoom="1" MaxZoom="50" ZoomSpeed="1.1">

    <Grid width="1200" height="1200">

        <Button />

    </Grid>

</controls:Viewport
```

and add the theme to the `app.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Han.Wpf.ViewportControl;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />

</Application.Resources>
```

I know your not using the MatrixTransform but to constrain the control to the bounds of the parent is calculated like below:

```
    private void OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsEnabled)
        {
            var scale = e.Delta > 0 ? ZoomSpeed : 1 / ZoomSpeed;
            var position = e.GetPosition(_content);

            var x = Constrain(scale, MinZoom / _matrix.M11, MaxZoom / _matrix.M11);
            var y = Constrain(scale, MinZoom / _matrix.M22, MaxZoom / _matrix.M22);

            _matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(x, y, position.X, position.Y);

            ZoomX = _matrix.M11;
            ZoomY = _matrix.M22;

            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsEnabled && _capture)
        {
            var position = e.GetPosition(this);

            var point = new Point
            {
                X = position.X - _origin.X,
                Y = position.Y - _origin.Y
            };

            var delta = point;
            _origin = position;

            _matrix.Translate(delta.X, delta.Y);

            Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

In the Invalidate call `Constrain()`

```
    private double Constrain(double value, double min, double max)
    {
        if (min > max)
        {
            min = max;
        }

        if (value <= min)
        {
            return min;
        }

        if (value >= max)
        {
            return max;
        }

        return value;
    }

    private void Constrain()
    {
        var x = Constrain(_matrix.OffsetX, _content.ActualWidth - _content.ActualWidth * _matrix.M11, 0);
        var y = Constrain(_matrix.OffsetY, _content.ActualHeight - _content.ActualHeight * _matrix.M22, 0);

        _matrix = new Matrix(_matrix.M11, 0d, 0d, _matrix.M22, x, y);
    }
```