# How can I set mousewheel zoom out limit on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas and I'm adding shapes to this canvas. I zoom with the mouse wheel. However, when I zoom out, I don't want to zoom out any further from the initial view of the canvas. The **zoom out limit** should be up to the **first image border**. How can I do that? My codes are below.

Otherwise, a bad image will occur and users can add shapes to the shrinking image, which goes beyond its purpose.

How can I set the mouse wheel zoom out limit on the canvas?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var json ='{"version":"3.1.0","objects":[{"type":"group","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":194,"top":157,"width":40,"height":80,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"id":"1047","objects":[{"type":"rect","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-20,"top":-15,"width":35,"height":50,"fill":"blue","stroke":"blue","strokeWidth":5,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"rx":0,"ry":0,"id":"1047"},{"type":"text","version":"3.1.0","originX":"center","originY":"top","left":0,"top":-40,"width":36,"height":20.34,"fill":"red","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"white","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"text":"1047","fontSize":18,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Quicksand","fontStyle":"normal","lineHeight":1.16,"underline":false,"overline":false,"linethrough":false,"textAlign":"left","textBackgroundColor":"","charSpacing":0,"styles":{}}]},{"type":"group","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":640,"top":473,"width":40,"height":80,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"id":"1048","objects":[{"type":"rect","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":-20,"top":-15,"width":35,"height":50,"fill":"blue","stroke":"blue","strokeWidth":5,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"rx":0,"ry":0,"id":"1048"},{"type":"text","version":"3.1.0","originX":"center","originY":"top","left":0,"top":-40,"width":36,"height":20.34,"fill":"red","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"white","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"text":"1048","fontSize":18,"fontWeight":"normal","fontFamily":"Quicksand","fontStyle":"normal","lineHeight":1.16,"underline":false,"overline":false,"linethrough":false,"textAlign":"left","textBackgroundColor":"","charSpacing":0,"styles":{}}]}],"backgroundImage":{"type":"image","version":"3.1.0","originX":"left","originY":"top","left":0,"top":0,"width":780,"height":646,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","stroke":null,"strokeWidth":0,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeDashOffset":0,"strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":4,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"backgroundColor":"","fillRule":"nonzero","paintFirst":"fill","globalCompositeOperation":"source-over","transformMatrix":null,"skewX":0,"skewY":0,"crossOrigin":"","cropX":0,"cropY":0,"src":"https://i1.wp.com/onideal.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Schlafzimmer-Grundriss-ideale-Position-Bett-Moebel-Kleiderschrank-dreieckchen-4-780x646.jpg?fit=780%2C646&ssl=1","filters":[]}}'
canvas.loadFromJSON(json, () => canvas.renderAll(), (o,object) => {
  object.on('selected', () => {
    console.log(object.id);
  });
});
//canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://i.hizliresim.com/iBHC0t.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));


//var uniqid = "0";
var uniqids = 0;
$("#door").on("click", function(e) {
  rect = new fabric.Rect({
        id:uniqid,
                left: 40,
                top: 40,
                width: 35,
                height: 50,      
                fill: 'blue',
                stroke: 'blue',
                strokeWidth: 5,
                strokeUniform: false,
                hasControls : true,
                 });  
  
                var uniqid = uniqids.toString(); 
  
               var text = new fabric.Text(uniqid, {
                  fontSize: 30,
                  originX: 'center',
                  originY: 'right'
                });
                
                var group = new fabric.Group([ rect, text ], {
                  left: 0,
                  top: 100,
                });
                                        
              canvas.add(group);
        uniqids++;
  
      canvas.on('selection:cleared', c => {
              console.log("empty");
          });
 
  
});
//*****************************
canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(opt) {
  var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
  var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
  zoom *= 0.999 ** delta;
  if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
  if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
  canvas.setZoom(zoom);
  opt.e.preventDefault();
  opt.e.stopPropagation();
  
})

$('#getid').click(function() {
  var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObjects();
  alert(canvas.getActiveObject().id); 
});



//***************************************

$("#save").on("click", function(e) {
    $(".save").html(canvas.toSVG());
});

$('#delete').click(function() {
  var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObjects(); 
    canvas.discardActiveObject();
    canvas.remove(...activeObject); 
});

/*
canvas.on('mouse:over', function(e) {
    e.target.set('fill', 'red');
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
  canvas.on('mouse:out', function(e) {
    e.target.set('fill', 'green');
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
*/
```

```css
#c {
  background-color: grey;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.1.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="door">Door</button>
<button id="delete">Delete Door</button>
<button id="save">Save</button>
<button id="getid">GET ID</button>
 

<p>Save bastıktan sonra altta SVG dosyası oluşur</p>
<br> 
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
<br>  
<p class="save">
</p>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47771871/how-to-set-panning-limits-on-wpf-canvas-based-on-zoom-level https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47771871/how-to-set-panning-limits-on-wpf-canvas-based-on-zoom-level https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47771871/how-to-set-panning-limits-on-wpf-canvas-based-on-zoom-level CLICK THE LINK CLICK IT

Comment: @VeryGoodCoder111 None of those are relevant to this question; different thing, if not entirely different language.  Sure, it could be argued that in an agnostic way, the answers in that link could apply to this one, but I'm not sure about that.  I don't know WPF, but it isn't JS.